# Indent Multiple Lines of <p> HTML Tag

Tags: css, user-interface

Is there any way to indent multiple lines of text from a single HTML `<p>` element?

For example, let's say I want to indent the first 2 or 3 lines, instead of just one line? Is there a CSS property for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with CSS by adding a pseudo element at the start of the `p` that is exactly the height of two (or three, or however many you need) lines and that has a set width, and applying `float: left`. The `p` text will wrap around this pseudo element giving the appearance of a multi line indent.

For example, if I know that my `p` lines will each be `1.2em` in height I can indent the first two lines by `30px` by adding a pseudo element that is `2.4em` high and `30px` wide:

```css
p {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
p::before {
    content: '';
    float: left;
    height: 2.4em;
    width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sit amet luctus turpis. Curabitur id varius tortor. Proin consequat quam eros, id sodales quam auctor vitae. Maecenas porttitor, eros mattis tincidunt porta, est eros iaculis ante, ac sodales dolor massa eget nunc. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sit amet luctus turpis. Curabitur id varius tortor. Proin consequat quam eros, id sodales quam auctor vitae. Maecenas porttitor, eros mattis tincidunt porta, est eros iaculis ante, ac sodales dolor massa eget nunc.</p>
```